# Find the "closest Float key" in a HashMap given a Float value

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Have a `LinkedHashMap<Float, Integer>`. The keys of this HashMap are points in time in seconds (like `0.031f` or `1.4021f`). There can be hundreds of thousands of entries.

Given a `float` value, say `0.6102f`, I need to find the HashMap key **that is closest to it** (like `0.6002f` maybe, assuming that's in the keyset).

A trivial answer would be to check key by key of the HashMap. After all, the entries happen to be correctly sorted. But I guess that's an `O(n)` operation which may not be a great idea given that I  have to perform this search several times per second.

Is there an efficient way to find the "closest float key" of a HashMap given a float?

Comment: If you are not bound to the use of HashMap, you may be interested in using a TreeMap.

Answer (score 3):

There is no efficient way to do this using a `HashMap`; i.e. nothing that is better than `O(N)` where `N` is the number of entries in the map.

However, if you switch to using a `TreeMap<Float, Integer>` you can find the entry with the closest key in `O(logN)`.  You need to use `floorEntry` and `ceilingEntry` and then test which of the 2 entry keys is nearest to your given key.

---

> After all, the entries happen to be correctly sorted.

Actually the keys in a `HashMap` aren't sorted.  The `hashCode()` implementations for some key types may make appear that the `HashMap` keys are sorted, but what you are seeing is an artifact.